# Using multiple bench PSU for three outputs +/-18V, +11V for old synth

Tags: power-supply, analog, power-electronics, synthesizer

I am trying to power a vintage synthesizer (Roland MKS-30) on my bench without having to have the transformer and raw AC parts out near where I will be working.

The PSU of the synth has two rectifiers after the transformer. After the two rectifiers is a 7805 voltage regulator for 5V and there is an M5230 regulator IC that is a variable output voltage regulator with a dual tracking, which then gives the +/- 15V.
Unfortunately my triple output PSUs all have a fixed 5V output.

Since I am trying to not use the A/C mains and just use straight DC, is it safe to tie my two bench PSU like I have in the diagram? I am looking to use one (in series mode) to make +/-18V, so after the rectifier and regulator I will have about +/-15V and the other (in independent mode) one get +11V from one of the channels.
Does this make sense?

[image: dual triple output bench PSU to create three channels]
[image: mks30 psu]